# GridView with Fix Header for each column in Android

Tags: android, android-gridview, gridview-sorting

I can't find any specific way that can make Android GridView having Header for each and every column like in asp.net we can make like this:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/614041/GridView-with-Fixed-Header-and-Scroll-Bar
How to make custom GrideView in android like this because default android gridview doesn't support header I found some useful library but its only support header for whole GridView not for specific column see this.https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter ,I also want to sort column on header click like:http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-how-to-column-sorting/

Comment: As an idea, you could add a GridView on top of your GridView.

Comment: Take a look at this http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html